# How should I try to evaluate this integral $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+4\sin^2\frac x2 - 4\sin\frac x2}\;dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose that we are given the following integral:

$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+4\sin^2\frac x2 - 4\sin\frac x2}\;dx.$$

([Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLzxw.png))

And the answer is one of these :-

> 1. $4\sqrt3-4-\frac\pi3$
> 2. $\pi-4$
> 3. $\frac{2\pi}3 - 4 - 4\sqrt3$
> 4. $4\sqrt3-4$

([original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go3r3.png)  )

Is there a way to **check** each answer and reach to the question (like in case of indefinite integral I can differentiate the options and match it with question and tick the correct answer) **or maybe confirm that this value is correct for the question without solving.**

Comment: No, but here you can get rid of the square root quite easily and just integrate can't you?

Comment: Some of these values are negative for starters...

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan please explain how do I get rid of square root

Comment: What is $(1-2\sin(x/2))^2$?

Comment: If this is multiple choices, I'd immediately answer 1 because its value greater than 0 and we can easily notice that the answer must have term of $\pi$ because there is integral of $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{x}{2}-4\sin\frac{x}{2}+1}\,dx&=\int_0^\pi\sqrt{\left(2\sin\frac{x}{2}-1\right)^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}\left(1-2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\pi\left(2\sin\frac{x}{2}-1\right)\,dx\\
&=\left[x+4\cos\frac{x}{2}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{3}+\left[-4\cos\frac{x}{2}-x\right]_\frac{\pi}{3}^\pi\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3}+4\cos\frac{\pi}{6}-4-\pi+4\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{3}\\
&=4\sqrt{3}-4-\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align}
If this is multiple choices, I'd immediately answer 1 because its value greater than $0$ and we can easily notice that the answer must have term of $\pi$ because there is term integral of $1$ that yield $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but, I asked something else!

Comment: This is terribly incorrect. You forgot absolute values. Your answer is negative but we are integrating a positive function.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, you are right the answer is the 1st option.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why only my answer get down vote?? Meanwhile Sanath Devalapurkar's answer not!? (T-T)

Comment: @V-Moy I didn't doun-voted either of the answers.

Comment: @MukulKumar Of course you're not. You have no enough reputation to do that.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I've edited my answer! I didn't check it the limits of integral. Now, would you vote up again my answer, please? I'm begging you.

Comment: Do not beg for upvotes. It is not appropriate.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I know that but I feel it's unfair because only me get voted down. At least give me a chance to edit my answer. I just didn't plot the function and immediately answer the question before someone else.

Comment: @V-Moy Thanks a lot, I just wanted to hear the last statement.

Comment: Yay! Thank you @MukulKumar. (>‿◠)✌

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1+4\sin^2(x/2)-4\sin(x/2)=(1-2\sin(x/2))^2$.

Now comes the only slightly tricky thing. Note that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.

The function $1-2\sin(x/2)$ is $\ge 0$ for $0\le x\le \pi/3$, and it is $\lt 0$ on the rest of our interval. So our integral is
$$\int_0^{\pi/3} (1-2\sin(x/2))\,dx+ \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} (2\sin(x/2)-1)\,dx.$$

**Remark:** It is not clear how to work backwards *in general* from numerical answers. One can consider for each whether it is numerically plausible, at the most basic level whether it has the right sign. Thus (2) and (3) are impossible. But such a procedure gives no guarantee of ruling out all the wrong answers. It comes fairly close in this case, since the intended "trap" was in taking the square root, so two negative "answers" were supplied. A glance at the integral after we set it up  also shows that there must be a "$\pi$" term, eliminating (4).

Comment: I agree-this problem needs to be worked directly and in that regard, it's more a test of the student's knowledge of basic algebra and trigonometric identities then calculus per se. The real trick here is recognizing how to transform the expression into a much simpler form. The moral of the story is to master the basics because they never cease playing a role in problem solving.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+4\sin^2\frac x2 - 4\sin\frac x2}\;dx=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\left(1-2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2}\;dx=\\
\int_0^{\pi/3} \left(1-2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\;dx+\int_{\pi/3}^\pi \left(1-2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\;dx\\
\text{This you can evaluate.}$$
Since the answers are numerical, there is no way which I know through which you can get the integral back. Let me give an example:
$$4\sqrt{3}-4=4(\sqrt{3}-1)=4\left.\left(\sqrt{x}-\dfrac{x}{3}\right)\right|^3_0=4\int^3_0\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)dx$$
As is visible, you can't derive back the integral $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+4\sin^2\frac x2 - 4\sin\frac x2}\;dx$ just given the numerical value of the integral, **as there are many other integrals that give back the exact same value.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but, I asked something else!

Comment: @MukulKumar You said in the comments, "please explain how do I get rid of square root". This is what I did to explain that.

Comment: Is that really a "hint"?

Comment: @Sanath Devalapurkar you should have answered that query in comments, answering here means you answered to the topic,The main question.

Comment: @MukulKumar I edited my question. Please do have a look at it.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Getting back The integral is not necessary but to check through answers that which one is the correct answer is necessary.

Comment: @MukulKumar See Andre Nicolas's edit. That is what I was trying to convey through an example.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar You're lucky. Before you edited your answer, we got the same result but only my answer got voted down. It's unfair!